# Why is my SQL statement sometimes slow and sometimes fast?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.45 on Windows Server 2016.  I'm executing the following statement in MySQL Workbench version 6.3.

```
delete FROM childattendance WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR) limit 100000;
```

Essentially I'm deleting any records older than 2 years. I'm not worried about which records get deleted as long as they're older than 2 years.  I actually want to delete all records older than 2 years but I'm limiting to 100,000 rows at a time so that the statement actually finishes before losing connection.

The weird thing is that sometimes this statement times out, and other times it executes within a few seconds.

See this screenshot for the result, running the same query five times:

[image]

The first time it ran for 11 seconds before losing connection (I don't know what's causing that either) and the second time I ran it and it executed successfully in 2 seconds.  Ten minutes later I ran it again, failing twice and succeeding once in between.

I've run the same statement limiting to 30000 rows and had the same issue.  Sometimes it goes for 11 seconds and times out.  Other times it executes in 2 seconds.  And I've seen the same thing with other queries.

Coincidentally `mysqldump` also loses connection to the server when trying to backup this very same table, although it lasts 13 seconds before dying, and it happens 100% of the time.  I don't know if that's related.

This table has approximately 6.4 million rows in 471 MB.

What causes this?

Comment: Your request (LIMIT without ORDER BY) does not make sense - it deletes **random** records from the list of records matched WHERE condition. *Sometimes it goes for 11 seconds and times out. Other times it executes in 2 seconds.* I think it can be an effect of block joining. When delete, fill factor of table/index block decreases. When its value became lower than some preset level the neighboring blocks are joined. This process needed in a lot of disk operations which are slow.

Comment: @Akina I don't understand your comment about "block joining".  can you rephrase please and help me understand what I can do to mitigate this.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion... Could you copy all records that are less than 2 years, drop the entire table and dump the copied records back in?

Comment: That would be over 4 million records.  I'm not sure how I would go about making a copy of that many rows.  mysqldump fails every time on this table.

Comment: `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` is almost always cause for alarm, because it suggests (though does not prove) that the query is actually causing the server to "exit" (crash) and restart.  Review the MySQL Server's error log before doing anything else.  If `mysqldump` fails, too, that's also a very bad sign.  Neither of these things are normal or expected.  Find and repair the problem.  The performance difference is uninteresting and not meaningful until then.

Comment: I agree Michael.  I've been trying to resolve this connection/mysqldump issue for several months now with no luck.  I thought maybe the answer to this question I posed might give me a clue.  Why is it sometimes o.k. and sometimes not?

Comment: The term "block split" is not new for you? Block join (or merge) is opposite process.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer has a mixture of explanation ("why" slow versus fast), speedup (how to be more efficient), and non-blocking (how to avoid the trouble with mysqldump).

- If few rows are that old, the main effort is scanning the entire table.  This can be helped significantly via `INDEX(date)`
- If more than 100K rows are that old, then the main effort is saving 100K rows in case of a undo (rollback).  This can be quite costly.  Don't do more than 1K at a time.
- If the count is somewhere in between, then there is both the table scan and some of the undo effort.  Note that it may find rows to delete early in the scan, or late -- thereby making this take an unpredictable amount of time.

While the lengthy `DELETE` is running, other things may be adversely affected -- such as timeouts in mysqldump.  So, the goal is to keep the `DELETE` down to only a few seconds, both by speeding it up and by decreasing how much you bite off at a time.

My [*Big Delete*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) blog explains several ways to significantly improve your task.

Note that one of my techniques focuses on what to do if you are deleting more than half the table.  This involves copying over the rows to *keep*.  (See the details on `RENAME TABLE`, etc)

Comment: Thanks Rick.  I'll take a closer look at your blog tomorrow.  As for your suggestion to not do more than 1K at a time, that's just not an option when you have 2 million rows to delete.

Comment: @Vincent - Plan A: do 100K at a time and live with the consequences; Plan B: write a stored proc that has a loop doing 1K at a time until finished.

Comment: @Vincent - Also, you may have noticed that the second 100K ran slower than the first?  If so, things may get slower and slower.  That's where my technique of using the PK to "pick up where you left off" rather than scanning from the start will benefit performance a lot.